# php based Business Instelligence system

Tags: php, reporting, business-intelligence

I have a LAMP host, not tomcat therefore no java, I need a Business Intelligence Tool which can be run on mysql/php

Must be able to download large reports

Comment: Can you define "business intelligence" for us, please?  What tools, exactly, do you require?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) reporting solution. myDBR is very easy to install on a LAMP server (wizard based installation). Once installed you can write your reports directly from the web-interface using the built in Query Browser.